# Apache: How to have multiple sites for one ServerName?

Tags: apache

I have a site testing.mycompany.com/api and testing.mycompany.com/web. How do I configure this in apache?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName testing.somedomain.com
        ServerAlias testing.somedomain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project-2/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName testing.mycompany.com/api
        ServerAlias testing.mycompany.com/api

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project-1/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The moment I configure it as above, there will be a fallback to the first virtual host (testing.somedomain.com).

When I remove the /api, then it works. However I want configure another virtual host with /web. How can I accomplish this? Apparently ServerName doesn't allow paths after the root url?

Comment: When you say "there will be a fallback", do you mean that accessing "testing.mycompany.com/api" results in data being served from /var/www/project-2/ ?

Comment: `testing.somedomain.com` and `testing.somedomain.com/api` cannot be separate virtual hosts. One is the site root, the other is a path under that root

Comment: @arco444 has a point. Even though `testing.somedomain.com` and `testing.mycompany.com` are different, `testing.mycompany.com/api` is not a valid ServerName. You should configure a host for `testing.mycompany.com` and possibly create a separate `<Location>` configuration for `/api` within it.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul yes correct. it will be directed to project-2. Wat is a <Location> configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testing.mycompany.com is the [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername)

/api and /web are [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) or [Location](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location).

If /api and /web are outside of your document root, you must use Alias.

Ex:

Document root of testing.mycompany.com = /var/www/

/api is a html page in /opt/myapi

/web is php page in /opt/web

So, inside your serverName you want 2 Alias.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName testing.mycompany.com
        ServerAlias testing.mycompany.com

        Alias /api /path/to/folder/where/is/api/files
        Alias /web /path/to/folder/where/is/web/files

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project-1/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```